# how to restrict <inpu type="text"> typed value not more than 10 using directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to restrict input typed length should not be more than 10 using directive in angularjs?
i do not know how to get typed value into directive?

```
app.directive('findLength',function(){
return{
restrict : 'EA',
require:'ngModel',
link:function(scope,ele,attr,ctrl){
console.log(ctrl.ngModel);
}
}

});
```

Comment: Check my answer it is easy to understand and works like you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this. This should be useful to you

HTML

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
   <input type='text' ng-model='test' allowed-length='10' check-length/>
   <span style='color:red;' ng-if='test.length === 10'>* Maximum 10 characters allowed</span>
</div>
```

Notice that i have used the `allowed-length` attribute so that the directive `checkLength` can be reusable for all length values. This is why we use directive as they can be reused again and again. So the best way is to provide the limit of length to the directive rather than coding the length inside the directive.

The directive is

```
.directive('checkLength',function(){
  return {
   restrict: 'A',
   scope:{
     ngModel: '=',
     allowedLength :'='
   },   
   link: function (scope, element) {
     element.on('keypress', function(event) {      
            if(scope.ngModel.length === scope.allowedLength){
                event.preventDefault();
              }else{
                scope.ngModel = element.val();
              }
       });
    }
   }
 })
```

This just works as expected. For your simplicity here is the attached link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6xsfs815/3/)

Comment: Hi @AKA,Thanks again ;-).but i want to show error if i type more than 10 characters

Comment: can we use require require:'ngModel' instead of scope,and add controller inside link function to get ng-model value

Comment: I have updated the code and it shows the error message when length reaches the limit. Check the working JSFIDDLE

Comment: great @AKA you are master in angular

Comment: i did it @AKA :-)

Comment: Thanks. AngularJS has been a easy framework. It is just we need to think it in Angular way to make it work :-)

Comment: Thanks you for your response again and again.Could please tell me brief about angular directive because i studied many tutorials to learn directive around 2 months but still i am not able to understand that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148103/discussion-between-aka-and-user7098427).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template to this directive using ng-maxlength.

Check this out: [Example plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/2ngL0R/preview)

You can "max-length" as attribute in your input instead of Ng-maxlength.

Comment: but i want to do with the help of directive

Comment: IN JS:

app.directive('findLength',function(){
    var validation= {};
    validation.scope = {
        maxlength: '=ngMaxlength',
        model: '=ngModel'
    };
    validation.template = '<input type="text" ng-model="model" ng-maxlength="maxlength"/>';
    return validar;
});

IN HTML:

<findLength ng-model="foo" ng-maxlength="bar"></findLength>

Try this out!

Comment: please give me a brief.i am not able to understand your code

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use ng-maxlength="10" angular pre defined Directive.

OR You can use Following Directive :-

app.directive('findLength',function(){
return{
restrict : 'EA',
require:'ngModel',
link:function(scope,ele,attr,ctrl){
angular.element(elem).on("keypress", function(e) {
     if(this.value>10)
          return false;
     else
       return true
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: if i use this i am not able to type any value inside <input type="text">

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {
      angular.element(element).on("keypress", function(e) {
        if (this.value.length > 10) {
          mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', false);
          e.preventDefault();
        } else {
          mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', true);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <p>Try writing in the input field:</p>

  <form name="myForm">
    <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required my-directive>
  </form>
```

Comment: Where you run this code bcuz its work on below code snippet